# LetterCapitalize CoderByte Error Ruby

Tags: ruby

I solved the [Letter Capitalize CoderByte](http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Letter%20Capitalize&lan=Ruby) on CoderByte but the console does not understand my code. It might have to do with their outdated 1.8.7 Ruby engine. I get this error:

```
(eval):1: undefined method `upcase' for 65:Fixnum (NoMethodError)   
from (eval):1:in `map'  
from (eval):1:in `LetterCapitalize' 
from (eval):6
```

I tested my codes on the latest version of Ruby on Repl.it and v2.0.0 on my computer and both places worked fine.

Here is my initial code:

```
def LetterCapitalize(str)
   str.split.map{|i| i[0].upcase+i[1..i.length]}.join(" ")
end
```

Initially I question whether my answer above is even correct or efficient. In an attempt to understand the error, what cause the 1.8.7 Ruby engine on Coderbyte to not understand the "upcase method"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the [1.8.7 version of `String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> If passed a single Fixnum, returns the code of the character at that position.

In [later versions](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) this returns a single character string, which is what you are expecting in your code.

You need to get a string here instead. One way would be to use the [`chr` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Integer.html#method-i-chr) to convert the Fixnum into a string:

```
str.split.map{|i| i[0].chr.upcase+i[1..i.length]}.join(" ")
```

Since `String` responds to `chr` this should work in later version of Ruby.

Another solution would be to use the two argument version of `[]`, which returns a string:

```
str.split.map{|i| i[0,1].upcase+i[1..i.length]}.join(" ")
```

Comment: Thanks! the documentation helps also!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this simple way: use [capitalize](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) method

```
def LetterCapitalize(str)
  str = str.split.map{|i| i.capitalize}.join(" ")
  return str 
end
```

I think your code is not correct for some scenario as on [Coderbyte](http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Letter%20Capitalize&lan=Ruby) asked

**For Eg:**

```
str = "heLlo woRld"
> str.split.map{|i| i[0].upcase+i[1..i.length]}.join(" ")
 => "HeLlo WoRld" #Only first character should be capital
```

Now check this code for same input:

```
> str.split.map{|i| i.capitalize }.join(" ")
 => "Hello World"
```

Comment: I was avoiding the `capitalize` method since some languages don't have capitalize method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like 1.8.7. doesn't provide upcase for fixnum, you can edit your code like it

```
def LetterCapitalize(str)
   str.split.map{|i| i[0].to_s.upcase+i[1..i.length]}.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: _No_ version of Ruby provides `Fixnum#upcase`.

Comment: this code does not raise an error but the `to_s` method converts the ASCII character into a string, so you end up seeing the string of the ASCII in your final answer. See @matt answer for the documentation